# Smbclient - vmware LINUX guest and windows Host - error opening local file

Tags: vmware, smb, parrot-os

I started doing the machine - dancing on hack the box.  I'm using Parrot LINUX vm on a windows host.  I connected to htb from my LINUX vm.  I'm able to connect smb but my get command isn't working.  It's throwing an error message saying 'error opening local file'. I checked my windows firewall permissions for smb and they're good.  Can anyone help me figure out where I need to tweak what...

Comment: Probably best to move this to SuperUser, since it's not a programming question, and more related to general computing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your file path. I had an error so I changed directory:

cd ~

then you can try again:

```
smbclient \\\\[Target]\\[FileShare]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try and copy the file using "scopy [File name] [New file name]" and it will make a copy of the file with a new name into the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a different command to open the file. Instead of using get or open, try the "more" command followed by the name of the file (extension included).